# What happens when RDS exceeds its provisioned IOPS in case of `Provisioned IOPS SSD (io1) volumes`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-ebs

Q1: What happens when AWS provisioned IOPS volume crosses its limit?

Q2: Do Amazon EBS provisioned IOPS volumes also refill credits like gp2, when it is running below baseline performance?

Comment: @mokugo-devops  i have set iops to 3k, but My rds is consuming 3.6k from last 5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

It will hit the threshold and stay there (not go any higher), and no it’s not burstable. You pay for the cap.

Comment: i have set iops to 3k,  but My rds is consuming 3.6k from last 5 hours. @mokugo-devops

Comment: I had purchased 3000 IOPS for RDS Oracle. I got ~ 9000 total IOPS for 30 - 45 mins.